# Best Practices to create a configuration kind of list in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer

we use to have a parameter list in our SharePoint environment, which contains Key value Pair for various configuration parameter, which we cache and use them  to improve the performance of our site.

Is there a way to implement the same in SharePoint Online.

Comment: It isn't any different than on prem

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you cache it but you can use Web.AllProperties (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.allproperties.aspx)

```
using (ClientContext cc = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    cc.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);
    cc.Site.RootWeb.AllProperties["key"] = "value";
}
```